# Saving tkinter button parameters to a file?

Tags: python, tkinter, save, pickle

I am trying to figure out how to save the parameters of a tkinter button by using pickle.

So far I'm thinking of putting all parameters within a string, saving the string and then defining the button's parameters from the string ?

It doesn't work at all, but it kinda looks like this:

```
def tapisone_on():
    tapisonevar = tkinter.StringVar(win,text= "TAPIS #1\nACTIF", bg="green", fg="black", command = tapisone_off)

def tapisone_off():
    tapisonevar = tkinter.StringVar(win,text= "TAPIS #1", bg="grey", fg="red", command = tapisone_on)

tapisonevar = tkinter.StringVar(win,'frameripple, text ="TAPIS #1", font=44, bg="grey", fg="red", command = tapisone_on')
tapisone = tkinter.Button(tapisonevar)
tapisone.place(relx=0.055, rely=0.105, relwidth = 0.2, relheight=0.4, anchor= "nw")
```

Do You have any idea how something like that can be done?

I need to be able to load what buttons where pressed down on a panel from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to use `pickle` to store `Button` options in a file and read them back later to use to actually create the corresponding widget. It assigns a name to each group of button options and creates an entry in a dictionary for them associated with that name. Each group of options is itself represented by a nested dictionary. This makes it easy to specify them when creating the `Button`s later on.

Note that this basic idea could be extended to also store other information about each button, such as where it should be placed.

```
import pickle
import tkinter as tk

def tapis_one():
    print('tapis_one executed')

def tapis_two():
    print('tapis_two executed')

tapis_btns = {
    'tapis_one': dict(text="TAPIS #1\nACTIF", bg="green", fg="black", command=tapis_one),
    'tapis_two': dict(text="TAPIS #1", bg="grey", fg="red", command=tapis_two)
}

# Save button parameters to file.
with open('buttons.pkl', 'wb') as outp:
    pickle.dump(tapis_btns, outp, -1)


#--- Sample usage of button parameters file.

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')

# Read button parameters file.
with open('buttons.pkl', 'rb') as inp:
    btn_dict = pickle.load(inp)

def create_button(btn_id):
    btn = tk.Button(root, **btn_dict[btn_id])
    btn.place(relx=0.055, rely=0.105, relwidth = 0.2, relheight=0.4, anchor= "nw")

tapis_two = tk.Button(text='Create tapis_two button',
                      command=lambda: create_button('tapis_two'))
tapis_two.pack(side='bottom')
tapis_one = tk.Button(text='Create tapis_one button',
                      command=lambda: create_button('tapis_one'))
tapis_one.pack(side='bottom')


root.mainloop()
```